# Should questions about specific algorithms include the algorithm tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Of the 1,188 questions with the [a-star](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a-star) tag ([search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a-star)), 465 have the [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) tag ([search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a-star+algorithm)).

Should these all have the algorithm tag since they are all about algorithms, in the same way a language-specific framework tag would typically have the programming language included with it (e.g. [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) for a [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) question involving Java code)?  The same question applies to other algorithms, of course; this was a specific example I ran across.

Comment: I personally don't see [algorithm] adding any value to a question already tagged [a-star], but I also don't see any harm in it. I'd opt for leaving things where they lie.

Comment: Look at it this way: would someone who's following the algorithm tag want to see the question? (probably yes) Would someone who's following the algorithm tag also follow every single tag related to algorithms? (probably not) To me that's the reason to have both the specific tag and the general tag.

Comment: The important tags here are [tag:algorithm] and [tag:graph-theory]. Very few people are watching [tag:a-star].

Comment: If the question is about algorithms themselves then the [algorithm] tag is appropriate; otherwise, probably not.  If the question is directly related to a specific algorithm then a tag for that algorithm is appropriate; otherwise, probably not.  These two sets overlap, but neither is a subset of the other.

Comment: The tag description is "An algorithm is a sequence of well-defined steps that defines an abstract solution to a problem. Use this tag when your issue is related to algorithm design." Kind of vague, "algorithm design" sounds to me like it would be used when devising your own algorithms and not necessarily for when you implement an existing one.